# Examine integer bit by bit (get and set)

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I need to do something like this:

```
For each bit in integer
  if (probability)
    flip the bit
  end
end
```

I know there is a cool trick `my_int[3]` to get the bit at an index, but this method can't *set* the bit.

Converting `to_s(2)` is too inefficient, ideally I'll be keeping them as integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitwise operators can be used for this:

`^` "exclusive or" to flip a bit

`|` "or" to set a bit

e.g. to set the nth bit:

```
x = x | (2 ** n) # or more concisely x |= 2 ** n
```

or to flip it

```
x = x ^ (2 ** n) # or more concisely x ^= 2 ** n
```

A range with `each` would be a way to implement your pseudo code:

```
(0...num_bits).each do |bit|
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Binary math!

```
n = 55
num_bits = Math.log2(n).ceil + 1
(0...num_bits).each do |bit_idx|
  mask = 1 << bit_idx

  # set bit
  n |= mask

  # unset bit
  n &= ~mask
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reframe that question to get a better answer. As I understand it, you want to randomly flip bits (or not). To give you the most flexibility, I would deconstruct this problem into two simpler problems.

1. Construct a bit mask to indicate which bits get flipped or not.
2. Use XOR on that bit mask to flip any bits set on the bit mask.

For step 1, you could just make up a random number up to the number of digits you want.

```
n = 137 # 10001001
bit_mask = rand(2**8) # 10110110
flipped = n ^ bit_mask # 00111111
# flip the first, third, fourth, sixth and seventh bits
# should be 00111111
# 63
```

And that's that.

Comment: This is awesome, but is there a way to make the probability weighted, instead of complete random? I only want to flip bits at a `0.002` chance

Answer (score 1):

### Bitwise Operations

I pulled bits from each answer to make:

```
# Getter
my_int[i]

# Setter—only works setting to 1, not to 0
my_int | 1 << i

# Setter—set to 0
my_int - (1 << i)

# Flipper
my_int ^ 1 << i
```